# Where the compressed dictionary is stored in zlib?

Tags: linux, dictionary, compression, zlib, deflate

In the dictionary implementation, It calculates adler check sum of the dictionary data, it places that in header and it sets FDICT flag in the header right ?. When there is match found in the data, deflate needs to point the dictionary instead of compressing it. For this we need to store this compressed dictionary data some where. Where is the compressed dictionary data is stored ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the dictionary on the receiving end where the decoder can find it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer. What is receiving end here ?

Comment: Where decompression is performed.